# Update 2 tables in single query, data not inserting mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query for updating the table like :

```
$updatetokenquery = "UPDATE `UsersNew` SET `DeviceToken`='".$newdtoken."',"
                                  . "`DeviceInfo`='".serialize($data['DeviceInfo'])."' , `DeviceType`='".strtolower($data['DeviceInfo']['OS'])."'"
                                  . "WHERE `HashedUid` ='".$newUserId."'";
```

I have another table `UsersOptStatus` where i need to update this table's `Actionkey` field also in the same query

**UPDATE**

i am using below query to update the new table.

```
$actionkey='loggedin';

$updatetokenquery = "UPDATE `UsersNew`, `UsersOptStatus` SET UsersOptStatus.Id=2, UsersOptStatus.Uid ='".$uid."', UsersOptStatus.CreatedDate=now(), UsersOptStatus.Action_key='".$actionkey."',  UsersNew.DeviceToken='".$newdtoken."',"
              . "UsersNew.DeviceInfo='".serialize($data['DeviceInfo'])."' , UsersNew.DeviceType='".strtolower($data['DeviceInfo']['OS'])."'"
              . "WHERE UsersNew.HashedUid ='".$newUserId."' ";

echo $updatetokenquery;
```

**Problem:**

Initially when i enter some id in the UsersOptStatus table and then if i hit the API, the data seems to be updating.

But when the table is empty, the new set of records are not inserting.

After manually inserting the values:

[image]

After inserting the values, if i run test with API, value in the action_key field is updating.

[image]

But if i just run the API without any values in table, no records are inserting.

Comment: `need help in completing the query completely` ... what is the problem with your code?  You never actually told us this.  You should be using prepared statements, but, if your code is running, then it's running.

Comment: Have updated my query string and error i get

Comment: I suspect that you have a typo in your query string.  Try doing `echo` on the query string after you have concatenated it, and I think you will see the problem more clearly.

Comment: I have corrected the query, i get succcess as response in postman, but why is the data not inserting in the new table?

Comment: You probably have some other problem with your PHP code.

Comment: Have updated the query, query seems to be updating...but the issue is when table is empty initially, records are not inserting, but if i add some value and then run the API, value seems to be updating

Answer (score 0):

Unknown column 'UsersOptStatus.Action_key' in 'field list'" 
Kindly check the Action_key column in UsersOptStatus table or it may be possible typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work unless there is some typo. 
The general syntax is

```
UPDATE table_1, table_2
   SET table_1.col1 = {newValue}, table_2.col3 = {anotherValue}
WHERE 
   table_1.col2 = {something}
```

Also please alias the table names to shorten the length of the query. *UsersOptStatus as uos*

Answer (score 0):

```
$updatetokenquery = "UPDATE `UsersNew`, `UsersOptStatus` SET UsersOptStatus.Action_key='".$actionkey."', UsersNew.DeviceToken='".$newdtoken."',"
          . "UsersNew.DeviceInfo='".serialize($data['DeviceInfo'])."' , UsersNew.DeviceType='".strtolower($data['DeviceInfo']['OS'])."'"
          . "WHERE UsersNew.HashedUid ='".$newUserId."' AND  UsersNew.Uid = UsersOptStatus.Uid  ";
```

Sorry, I didn't understand why are checking this UsersOptStatus.Action_key ='".$actionkey."'. Hope this help you.

Comment: Have updated the question and query @Lokesh, can you please tell why the data doesnt insert initially

Comment: @Sushivam in your updated query you are actually updating the cross correlation of UserNew and UserOptStatus tables i.e., "UPDATE `UsersNew`, `UsersOptStatus` .....". Even if any one of the table is empty the cross correlation will be a empty set. Hence updating a empty set results nothing.  Hope I am clear.